# module 'firebase_auth not found"

Tags: xcode, flutter, firebase-authentication, runner

[image]

Hello guys,
I have been trying to run my flutter code in IOS 11 simulator but after integrating firebase into my project i'm getting this error while running for IOS simulator. Is there anything i can do to solve it?

Comment: After integration in the flutter project have you launched XCode again from Android studio?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem,

First erase your `Pods/` and Podfile, then run

```
 $ flutter clean
```

then

```
$ flutter run
```

finally open in xcode `Runner.xcworkspace`

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem. These are what I performed to resolve. 
At your project folder:

```
flutter clean    
cd ios
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf Pods/*    
flutter build ios
cd ..
open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
```

if **flutter build ios** takes a long time u can improve building time by edit Podfile ([refer](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview)):

```
...
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '6.26.0'
...
```

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Pretty much anytime you run 'flutter clean', run 'flutter pub get' after or you are going to have issues, probably good to put that step in there